# Using regex to add a new line to a string every time each line reaches a certain length

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to ensure text does not appear outside of the window as the window size cannot be changed.

[image]

The image above shows what happens when the string of the order numbers exceeds the length of the window. I'm trying to ensure that when the length of the string of order numbers reaches a certain length, I use regex to make a new line for the next orders.

```
private String listOfOrders( Map<String, List<Integer> > map, String key )
  {
    String res = "";
    if ( map.containsKey( key ))
    {
      List<Integer> orders = map.get(key);
      for ( Integer i : orders )
      {
          res += " " + i + ",";
      }
    } else {
      res = "-No key-";
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

This is the code to display the text, it works by forming the string res and filling it with the order numbers from the array list.

I found, through researching, a cool little piece of code which replaces a string every set amount of characters with itself plus a new line.

```
    if(res.length() >= W-10)
    {
        res = res.replaceAll("(.{20})", "$1\n");
    }
    else
    {
        res += " " + i + ",";
    }
```

But this has no effect at all. And I also realised that this code can not tell how long each line is because I'm using length to determine the length of each line and not how long each line is between each "\n".

My question is, how do I go about using regex to ensure each line in the string is a certain number of characters long? As my attempt does not work. The above just provides context as to why I want lines in a string a certain legnth.

Thanks!

Comment: This should be done by your GUI toolkit, not regex. Depending on the font and text you can fit more or fewer than 20 characters into one line.

Comment: I suppose my question is how do I format a string with the constraint of not having more than a set number of characters on each line in the string

Comment: Are you using JTextArea? Or what?

Comment: I'm using in-built libraries. Canvas, Graphics and Containers!

Comment: Maybe `SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(FontMetrics fm,                   String str)` is what you are looking for?